# Failed to connect to: undefined - self signed certificate when connecting to MSSQL Server on Windows Authentication in Electron application

Tags: javascript, node.js, sql-server, typescript, electron

I am trying to connect to MSSQL database via Windows Authentication in Electron Application.

I use packages:
msnodesqlv8 2.1.0
mssql 7.0.0

As a result, when the pool is connected, the following is displayed:
Error occurred in handler for 'SqlQuery': ConnectionError: Failed to connect to : undefined - self signed certificate

My config code:

```
import { IResult, config } from "mssql";

    const connectionSettings: config = {
        server: "my_server_name",
        port: 1443,
        driver: "msnodesqlv8",
        options: {
            trustedConnection: true,
            connectionString: "Data Source=my_server_name;database=my_database;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False"
        }
    };
```

My connection code:

```
import { ConnectionPool, IResult, config } from "mssql";

public SqlQuery(poolOptions: config, query: string)
    : Promise<IResult<any>> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        console.log(poolOptions);
        const pool = new ConnectionPool({
            ...poolOptions
        });

        pool.connect()
            .then(() => {
                console.log("CONNECT");
                return pool.query(query);
            })
            .then(values => {
                console.log(values);
                return resolve(values);
            })
            .catch(reason => {
                reject(reason);
            });
    });
```

Comment: If the database server is configured with a self-signed cert, you need to specify `TrustServerCertificate=True`.

Comment: By default the SQL Server Setup program creates a self-signed X.509 certificate and assigns it to the instance. You have three choices: 1. use `TrustServerCertificate=True` as Dan Guzman mentioned; 2. log on to the Windows server running the SQL instance, export the public key of its X.509 certificate to a file and import that into your client computer's Trusted Certificates/Roots store; 3. Get a (trusted) X.509 certificate from a CA (or your organisation) and assign it to the SQL instance via SQL Server Configuration Manager.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning @DanGuzman
Unfortunately when I use
`trustServerCertificate=true`
I get error:
`Error: An error occurred while logging in user ""`

Comment: Maybe it is important, but i use this code in electron application.

Answer (score 1):

I also face the same error while connecting with SQL server using nodejs
First you have to **install mssql,stream and tedious dependency** in your project and then write the following code `

```
var sql = require("mssql");
var config = {
  user: "USER_NAME",
  password: "PASSWORD",
  server: "Your_SERVER_NAME",
  database: "DATABASE_NAME",
  port: 1433,
  options: {
    encrypt: false,
    useUTC: true,
  },

  pool: {
    max: 100,
    min: 0,
    idleTimeoutMillis: 3600000,
    connectionTimeout: 3600000,
    requestTimeout: 3600000,
  },
};
var database = new sql.ConnectionPool(config);

database
  .connect()
  .then(function () {
    console.log("connected");
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
  });`
```