# I have problem involved in Connection between nodejs and mssql

Tags: node.js, sql-server

I tried running this code but it shows the following error

```
'ConnectionError: Failed to connect to LAPTOP-VNS3VHIC:1433 - self signed certificate
    at C:\Users\dtvin\OneDrive\Máy tính\mssql\node_modules\mssql\lib\tedious\connection-pool.js:70:17
    at Connection.onConnect (C:\Users\dtvin\OneDrive\Máy tính\mssql\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:1038:9)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:482:26)
    at Connection.emit (events.js:375:28)
    at Connection.emit (C:\Users\dtvin\OneDrive\Máy tính\mssql\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:1066:18)
    at Connection.socketError (C:\Users\dtvin\OneDrive\Máy tính\mssql\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:1412:12)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\Users\dtvin\OneDrive\Máy tính\mssql\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:1177:14)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:387:35)
    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:106:8)
    at emitErrorCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:74:3) {
  code: 'ESOCKET',
  originalError: ConnectionError: Failed to connect to LAPTOP-VNS3VHIC:1433 - self signed certificate
      at Connection.socketError (C:\Users\dtvin\OneDrive\Máy tính\mssql\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:1412:28)
      at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\Users\dtvin\OneDrive\Máy tính\mssql\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:1177:14)
      at Socket.emit (events.js:387:35)
      at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:106:8)
      at emitErrorCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:74:3)
      at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:82:21) {     
    code: 'ESOCKET',
    isTransient: undefined
  }
}
RequestError: No connection is specified for that request.
    at Request._query (C:\Users\dtvin\OneDrive\Máy tính\mssql\node_modules\mssql\lib\base\request.js:493:37)
    at Request._query (C:\Users\dtvin\OneDrive\Máy tính\mssql\node_modules\mssql\lib\tedious\request.js:363:11)
    at Request.query (C:\Users\dtvin\OneDrive\Máy tính\mssql\node_modules\mssql\lib\base\request.js:429:12)
    at C:\Users\dtvin\OneDrive\Máy tính\mssql\index.js:14:16
    at Immediate.<anonymous> (C:\Users\dtvin\OneDrive\Máy tính\mssql\node_modules\mssql\lib\global-connection.js:56:7)
    at processImmediate (internal/timers.js:466:21) {
  code: 'ENOCONN'
}
undefined'
```

```
const sql = require('mssql')
const config = {
    user: 'sa',
    password: '123456789',
    server:'LAPTOP-VNS3VHIC',
    database: 'TestDb',
    port: 1433
};
sql.connect(config , function (err) {
    if(err) console.log(err);
    let sqlRequest = new sql.Request();

    let sqlQuery = 'Select * from Persons'
    sqlRequest.query(sqlQuery , function(err , data) {
        if(err) console.log(err);

        console.table(data)

        sql.close();
    })
})
```

Comment: Refer to [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67550729/failed-to-connect-to-undefined-self-signed-certificate-when-connecting-to-mss) and try the `TrustServerCertificate=True` suggestion

Comment: Took the words right out of my mouth, @SMor. :)

Answer (score -1):

I am running into a similar issue. I think the problem is because your node server application maybe running on a different network as the database server protected by a Firewall. Check with your org's cyber security folks to

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).